# When using `bundle gem floob`, why is a directory of the same name as the gem is created?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, setup-project, directory-structure

I am making my first gem. Let's assumed it is called `floob`. ex: `bundle gem floob`

Why would `bundle gem` create two directories of the *same name* for a gem? ex: `/floob/lib/floob/`

Do I put the bulk of my code in `/lib/floob/` (alongside the `version.rb` file?)

What is the purpose of the file that is created with the gem name? 
ex: `/floob/lib/floob.rb`

The only command run was `bundle gem`.

I would love a little clarification on what the relationship is between all the `floobs`~

Comment: Where and when does `bundle install` create this folder structure? Please be more specific. What commands did you run and where did you run them?

Comment: I was mistaken on the command it is `bundle gem`. I have updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this "two-tier" structure is because `/floob/lib` will ultimately be the folder that is added to the Ruby `require` load path.

This way if you put `floob.rb` into `/floob/lib`, you can load it with:

```
require 'floob'
```

This also gives the opportunity to separate subcomponents, like `version.rb`, under the `floob` namespace by putting them into `/floob/lib/floob`. That means you can now do things like:

```
require 'floob/version'
require 'floob/base'
require 'floob/core'
etc..
```

If `/floob` was directly added to the load path, then it would be difficult to separate code from things like `README` files, gemspecs, or other assets like images, binary blobs, YAML settings files or `bin` stubs.

Now the actual code will live under `lib`, and everything else can be put nicely into folders directly under `/floob`, without interfering with the code or load path functionality.

Also note that in most cases you should not put anything else than `floob.rb` into `/floob/lib`, because otherwise you will be polluting the global load path namespace. Instead all the rest of the code should be put into `/floob/lib/floob`, and then you put `require` code into `floob.rb` to load those files, like I described above.

This way you keep the load path clean, and components nicely separated from each other.