# Load error in gem even though bundle install is working well

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, environment

I am trying to build a gem on my computer and I do require 'RuPlot'.
Here is the output

```
/Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruplot (LoadError)
from /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from hello.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Here is my RubyGems Environment:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.11
- RUBY VERSION: 2.4.1 (2017-03-22 patchlevel 111) [x86_64-darwin16]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/arafat/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/arafat/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
- x86_64-darwin-16
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
 - /Users/arafat/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
```

Here is Bundler environment

### Environment

```
Bundler       1.16.1
Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-16
Ruby          2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
 Full Path   /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby
 Config Dir  /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/etc
RubyGems      2.6.11
 Gem Home    /Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
 Gem Path    /Users/arafat/.gem/ruby/2.4.0:/Users/arafat/.rbenv/versions /2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `bundle install`? You should run `gem install` to install system gems.

Comment: Did that too.   I did gem build and then gem install. Stil getting the same error.

Comment: Does the ruplot gem have a file named lib/ruplot.rb? Because that’s where Ruby will look.

Comment: I can't find any gem named ruplot on the net. Are you sure the name is correct? Can you post a website link for it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the file `ruplot.rb` in the `lib` folder:
https://github.com/Arafatk/RuPlot/tree/master/lib

You should add it there, because the `lib` folder is the folder that Ruby adds to the load path when you install the gem.

You can read my answer here for a further explanation of how you should structure your gem code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50300893/823617